# Error while attempting Dynamic load of Oracle client library in AIX

Tags: c, oracle, root, aix, dynamic-loading

I am working on a project and recently I have changed static linking of oracle client library to dynamic loading of library whenever it actually try to call a function from OCI (Oracle client library/ `libclntsh.so`), program will attempt `dlopen()` with absolute path to `libclntsh.so`. and it gives me following error

`┌────────────────────────────────── Error ──────────────────────────────────┐ 
│                      Could not open Dynamic Library:                       │ 
│  /aix64/oracle/client/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so (8013)            │ 
│                     DLL Error : Could not load module                      │ 
│ /aix64/oracle/client/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so. (8014)            │ 
│                   Unable to load shared library (14945)                    │ 
│  ORACLE error -1012 see "ORACLE Error Messages and Codes Manual". (1252)   │ 
│                                    **                                      │ 
│              Failed to connect to ORACLE database lh. (1451)               │ 
│                                                                            │ 
│ ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── │ 
│                                   <OK>                                     │ 
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘`

`PATH/LIBPATH` can't be the issue, as I am giving absolute path for `libclntsh.so` in `dlopen()`.

permission, owner and group of executable is:
`-rwsrwxr-x    1 root    frnd     25835393 Dec 13 19:18 /some/other/abc`

While looking for the solution, I got to know that because of sticky bit set and file is owned by root, when I execute it, it is not able to get `LIBPATH`.
Path to library is given, but two of its dependencies from same directory are not being loaded and hence this error.

Can anyone suggest something.

PS: When using 12.2.0.1.0 oracle library(ie: LIBPATH and ORACLE_HOME is pointing to /oracle/client/12.2.0.1.0/), there is no issue in loading. I don't understand how that happens.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should examine `libclntsh.so` to find out what dependencies it has: either `ldd libclntsh.so` or `dump -H -X64 libclntsh.so` will do.

It could be `libons.so` or `libclntshcore.so` depending on the version/variant.

Plus, the oracle client might open shared libraries with dlopen too (for InstantClient it is `libociei.so`.

To sum up: you should set `LIBPATH` to `/aix64/oracle/client/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib`, then it might work.

Comment: Thank you Lorinczy.
Yes, you are right. These two are among the dependencies of libclnthsh.so
And I have LIBPATH set to the client location. 
loading is successful if executable has this permission. ie. `-rwxrwxr-x`
but it fails when permission has SUID set. ie `-rwsrwxr-x`.
from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work) question's answer, we can see it will inherit `root`'s permission and environment. Hence it won't have LIBPATH set.
One workaround I have is setting soft-links for dependencies in /usr/lib .
but it will be messy.

Comment: Yes, LIBPATH might not work with set-uid. You could use ˙sudo˙ instead. Or, at linkage-time you could add option `-L/aix64/oracle/client/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib` to the command line, so the compiler should add this directory to the libpath (check the output of `dump -H -X64`)

Comment: Hi @Lorinczy, sorry I forget to check dump -H -X64 first time.
I have checked it now and I am surprised seeing some non-existent path in output of  ` /aix64/oracle/client/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so` .
path: `/usr1/oracle/app/12102/product/12.1.0/client_1/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib`

and for the 12.2 client installation the same path in `dump -H -X64` is `/aix64/oracle/client/12.2.0.1.0/client_2/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib` .
I think correct path results in successful loading with 12.2 client.

Can you tell me what does this path mean, and how to change it?

Comment: This libpath might contain elements that exist on the computer where the shared object was created, but don't exist on your computer. They cause no trouble, neither do they help. I don't think you could change this path, unless you re-link the shared object, but that isn't easy. (On the other hand, as a quick-hack you could create some directories/symlinks to (ab)use the built-in libpath.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Lorinczy, actually re-linking would be a good idea. 
I will update once it is done.
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Set uid programs will not load most PATH variables.

In /etc:.kshrc you can force loads as needed.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=files-kshrc-file